# Catch and encrypt attachment when email client tries to download

Tags: android, android-intent

I Want to develop a app which can identify corporate email accounts and when user tries to download the attachments i want to encrypt it before it getting saved in a device?

Is it possible?

If any body has any way to do it or any clue to do it please help.
If any body has any code snippet will be aapreciated

Many Many Thanks in Advance!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible?

Only if you write your own email client which has this feature.

Comment: If that is the case you might want to look at the open source project K9mail
https://github.com/k9mail/k-9/wiki